# Prevent duplicate record when read/show data in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I manage to show data from web page but the data has two record .When i check the reason it has the `duplicate id` . How do i prevent to show two data in one record . I expect to show single each data even the id was same .

The data was pulled from backend api by using guzzle

Here is my example data

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#902 ▼
    +"am_SN_no": "YESSZ0001243"
    +"am_tag_id": ""
    +"am_PO_no": ""
    +"am_model": "20107AC8A726"
    +"am_service_tag": ""
    +"am_supplier_ID": ""
    +"am_status_rec": "R01"
    
  }
  1 => {#918 ▼
    +"am_SN_no": "YESSZ0001243"
    +"am_tag_id": ""
    +"am_PO_no": ""
    +"am_model": "20107AC8A726"
    +"am_service_tag": ""
    +"am_supplier_ID": ""
    +"am_status_rec": "R02"
   
  }
]
```

the only difference of this data was am_status_rec .

this is code that i pull my data in controller using guzzle

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        

     $options = [
      'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'application/json',

      ],

      'query' => [

        'am_SN_no' => $id,



      ]
    ];



    $response = $this->client->post('readAsset', $options)->getBody();
    $content = json_decode($response->getContents());
    

    $result = $content->data;
    dd($result);


    return view('asset.AssetRead',compact('result'));

  }
```

Comment: if you want to get response without duplicate, you need to request the response from your backend (mysql group by). But if you dont want to request you need to use loop for that

Comment: thank you...just now realise need to refer backend

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GroupBy Query if you are using Laravel Eloquent

Answer (score -1):

in your validation ( from your controller), try this

```
     ['...'=>'....'
'am_SN_no'=>'required|unique:tale_name',
'....'=>'....',
]
```